# Is using pragma omp simd like this correct?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, simd

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define pow(x) ((x) * (x))
#define NUM_THREADS 8
#define wmax 1000
#define Nv 2
#define N 5

int b=0;

float Points[N][Nv]={ {0,1}, {3,4}, {1,2}, {5,1} ,{8,9}};

float length[wmax+1]={0};

float EuclDist(float* Ne, float* Pe) {
    int i;
    float s = 0;
 
    for (i = 0; i < Nv; i++) {
        s += pow(Ne[i] - Pe[i]); 
    }
    return s; 
}

void DistanceFinder(float* a[]){
    
    int i;
    #pragma omp simd
    for (i=1;i<N+1;i++){  
        length[b] += EuclDist(&a[i],&a[i-1]);
    }
    //printf(" %f\n", length[b]);
}



void NewRoute(){
//some irrelevant things

DistanceFinder(Points);
}

int main(){
    
omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);


do{
    b+=1;
    NewRoute();
    } while (b<wmax);
}
```

Trying to parallelize this loop and trying different things, tried this one.

Seems to be the fastest, however is it correct to use SIMD like that? Because I'm using a previous iteration (`i` and `i - 1`). The results I see though are correct weirdly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems to be the fastest, however is it correct to use SIMD like that?

First, there is a *race condition* that needs to be fixed, namely during the updates of the array `length[b]`. Moreover, you are accessing memory outside the array `a`; (iterating from `1` to `N + 1`), and you are passing `&a[i]`. You can fix the *race condition* by using OpenMP `reduction` clause:

```
void DistanceFinder(float* a[]){
    
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    float tmp;
    #pragma omp simd private(tmp) reduction(+:sum)
    for (i=1;i<N;i++){  
        tmp = EuclDist(a[i], a[i-1]);
        sum += tmp;
    }
    length[b] += sum;
}
```

Furthermore, you need to provide a version of `EuclDist` as follows:

```
#pragma omp declare simd uniform(Ne, Pe)
float EuclDist(float* Ne, float* Pe) {
    int i;
    float s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < Nv; i++)
        s += pow(Ne[i] - Pe[i]); 
    return s; 
}
```

> Because I'm using a previous iteration (i and i - 1).

In your case, it is okay, since the array `a` is just being read.

> The results I see though are correct weirdly or not.

Very-likely there was no vectorization taking place. Regardless, it would still be *undefined behavior* due to the aforementioned *race condition*.

You can simplify your code so that it increases the likelihood of the vectorization actually happening, for instance:

```
void DistanceFinder(float* a[]){
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    float tmp;
    #pragma omp simd private(tmp) reduction(+:sum)
    for (i=1;i<N;i++){  
        tmp = pow(a[i][0] - a[i-1][0]) + pow(a[i][1] - a[i-1][1]) 
        sum += tmp;
    }
    length[b] += sum;
}
```

A further change that you can do to improve the performance of your code is to allocate the matrix (that is passed as a parameter of the function `DistanceFinder`) in a manner that when you iterate over its rows (*i.e.,* `a[i]`) you would be iterating over continuous memory address.

For instance, you could pass two arrays `a1` and `a2` to represent the first and second columns of the matrix `a`:

```
  void DistanceFinder(float a1[], float a2[]){
        int i;
        float sum = 0;
        float tmp;
        #pragma omp simd private(tmp) reduction(+:sum)
        for (i=1;i<N;i++){  
            tmp = pow(a1[i] - a1[i-1]) + pow(a2[i][1] - a2[i-1][1]) 
            sum += tmp;
        }
        length[b] += sum;
    }
```